# Sort an array by more than one criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

1- Id person (key) and qualification (value), this array have a descending order : arsort

```
   Array
    (
        [61] => 02.30.00
        [95] => 02.30.00
        [19] => 02.01.00
        [131] => 02.00.00
        [58] => 01.60.00
        [97] => 01.50.00
        [76] => 01.40.00
        [20] => 01.30.00
        [112] => 01.10.00
        [42] => 01.10.00            
        [116] => 01.04.00
    }
```

2- ... and attempts associated to the Id person.

```
Array
(
    [131] => 1
    [58] => 1
    [61] => 1
    [112] => 2
    [116] => 1
    [42] => 1
    [19] => 1
    [20] => 1
    [76] => 1
    [97] => 1
    [95] => 1
)
```

I need to maintain the descending order but adding ascending order by the number of the attempts. My problem is with these values:

```
[112] => 01.10.00 | 2
[42]  => 01.10.00 | 1
```

How get this result?

```
Array
(
    [61] => 02.30.00 // 1
    [95] => 02.30.00 // 1
    [19] => 02.01.00 // 1
    [131] => 02.00.00 // 1
    [58] => 01.60.00 // 1
    [97] => 01.50.00 // 1
    [76] => 01.40.00 // 1
    [20] => 01.30.00 // 1
    [42] => 01.10.00 // 1
    [112] => 01.10.00 // 2
    [116] => 01.04.00 // 1
)
```

**Edit: ugly solution:**

```
    $new = array();
    foreach($qualification as $k => $r)
    {
        $new[$k] = array(
            'qualification'=> $r,
            'attempt'      => $attempt[$k],
            'id'           => $k,       
        );
    }

    foreach ($new as $key => $row)
    {
        $qlf[$key]      = $row['qualification'];
        $att[$key]      = $row['attempt'];
    }
    array_multisort($qlf, SORT_DESC, $att, SORT_ASC, $new);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($new as $row)
    {
        $result[$row['id']] = $row['qualification'];
    }
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This would be much easier achieved with a database where you can sort by more than one column.

Comment: I get this information from a form via POST

Comment: @silkfire A database is also just a system executing code. It's not hard to do this in PHP (QED, see below). The database just exposes a nice, simple domain language for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uksort($qualification, function ($a, $b) use ($qualification, $attempt) {
    return strcmp($qualification[$a], $qualification[$b])
        ?: $attempt[$a] - $attempt[$b];
});
```

I'm not entirely sure about which order you want to sort what in, but the above code will do; you just may have to switch `$a` and `$b` for reversing the order of one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for *not* zipping the arrays to form another copy of the arrays when sorting in place works beautifully!

Comment: for the question only I need change: strcmp($result[$b], $result[$a]) ... amazing solution! thanks!

Comment: Well deceze you really came up with an advanced solution, but I'd go with the database solution any day :)

Comment: @silkfire *If* your data comes from a database in the first place. Then yes, certainly. This also isn't really all that "advanced", it's just practically applied sorting.

Comment: First time I see such an advanced use of usort anyway, I'm not attempting to criticize you or anything, on the contrary I think it's a brilliant and unexpected solution. By the way, what kind of syntax is `?:`? Shoudn't there be something in between there?

Comment: @silkfire You need to stay up to date with your language... ;) http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @deceze Fantastic, didn't know about that little feature when using the ternary operator. Spontaeously I'd read that as a syntax error ;)